# How To Partially transpose data held in a List

Tags: vb.net

Hi there hoping for some much needed assistance, I have a List object which contains the following content:

[image]

Which needs transposing to the following:

[image]

The data is acquired via a WebAPI which delivers the data in JSON as per the attached data sets.  Here is the code relevant to process:

```
 Public Class Voltage

      Private _timestamp As String
      Private _groupId As String
      Private _groupName As String
      Private _mapTag As String
      Private _tagName As String
      Private _NominalVoltage As String
      Private _ActualVoltage As String
 
 End Class

 Public Class VoltageList
      Inherits List(Of Voltage)
      Public Sub New()
      End Sub
 End Class


  Public Sub GetVoltages()
      Dim voltage As Voltage = Nothing
      Dim voltages As VoltageList = Nothing
      Dim json As String
      Dim crit As HttpCriterion
      Dim district As LookupItem
      Dim tmpSt As String
      Dim tmpEn As String

      Try

           _fileTimeStamp = DateTime.Now

           tmpSt = New DateTime(_timeSpec.StartTime.Year, _timeSpec.StartTime.Month, _timeSpec.StartTime.Day, 0, 0, 0).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")
           tmpEn = New DateTime(_timeSpec.EndTime.Year, _timeSpec.EndTime.Month, _timeSpec.EndTime.Day, 0, 0, 0).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")

           _logger.SendLog("Started data compilation  - " & DateTime.Now.ToString, NLog.LogLevel.Info)
           _logger.SendLog("Querying  " & _transformerList.Count & " datapoints.", NLog.LogLevel.Info)

           'Get the voltage information via the webapi
           For Each _tx In _transformerList
                crit = New HttpCriterion
                crit.Interval = _piInterval
                crit.StartTime = tmpSt
                crit.EndTime = tmpEn
                crit.TagFilter = ChangeEngUnit(_tx.Tx_tag_kv)
                crit.Delimiter = _delim
                crit.ServerName = _serverName

                If crit.TagFilter <> "No kV Tag" Then
                     _logger.SendLog("Querying  " & _tx.Group_name & "  -  datapoint: " & _tx.Tx_tag_kv, NLog.LogLevel.Trace)

                     Try
                          json = GetCriteriaJson(crit)
                          GetData(_clients(0), json)

                          'Convert JinterimResults to VoltagesList and append to final results
                          AppendInterim()

                          'Now enrich the data for completion of the final result set
                          DataEnrich()

                          'Now transpose the data so that transformers per site are stored by column
                          Transpose()

                     Catch ex As Exception
                          _logger.SendLog("ODSDataPackager.GetVoltages", NLog.LogLevel.Error, ex)
                          'Throw
                     End Try
                End If

                'Reset class variables for the new district
                _interimResults = Nothing
                _jinterimResults = Nothing

           Next

           'Now write the voltage information out to a CSV file
           Export()

           _logger.SendLog("Data compilation completed - " & DateTime.Now.ToString, NLog.LogLevel.Info)

           If Not System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached = True Then
                _logger.SendLog("Voltages have been loaded.  Number of records - " & voltages.Count, NLog.LogLevel.Info)
           End If

      Catch ex As Exception
           _logger.SendLog("ODS Data Packer Failed while compiling data for " & _tx.Group_name & "  -  datapoint: " & _tx.Tx_tag_kv, NLog.LogLevel.Info)
           _logger.SendLog("ODSDataPackager.GetVoltages", NLog.LogLevel.Error, ex)
           Throw
      Finally

      End Try
 End Sub
```

The Transpose() call is where the issue is.  I am at a loss as to how to proceed, the source of the data is a time series database with no transform capability (as would be the case if the were from Oracle or SQLServer for instance), are there any techniques in .Net that would allow me to achieve this?

Kind Regards
Paul J.

Comment: I think you need to have a look at Export()

Comment: Could you perhaps update your question with a little more detail about what this Transpose() method supposed to do.  It's a little hard for anyone to understand what that method does if you don't actually add it to your question.  If you're wanting help writing the method, maybe even edit your post and explain the logic for exactly your data is transposed

Comment: The problem is not in the Transpose() routine. If he wants to change the order ot the columns, it has to be done in his Export() function.

Comment: @NickAbbot I'm kind of working on the assumption whatever the Transpose() method does is prep the data for the Export(), however since we don't have detail on either method really, we are just guessing

Comment: No. Transpose is a standard call when going from json, a columnar list of data, to a tabular representation - it's all part of parsing json. All json apis do it somewhere. The Export(), however, clearly says "Now write the voltage information out to a CSV file" and is where the fields are outputted in whatever order is desired.

Answer (score 0):

apologies for taking so long to get back to you.  I resolved my issue by creating a new class reflecting the columnar structured required then looping through each element in the source dataset and based on the component identifier (Component1, Component2 etc...) allocating the value to the correct property in the class
.